# AS3 - Mac CS6, Can't import mx.utils.ObjectUtils

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm running CS6 on my mac and no matter what I try, I can't seem to import mx.utils.ObjectUtils. I can't find it in the code suggestion and if I try to import it, I get this:

> Line 4 1172: Definition mx.utils:ObjectUtil could not be found.

So, any ideas how I can use the package?

Answer (score 0):

[`mx.utils.ObjectUtil`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html) is only available for flex :

> The ObjectUtil class is an all-static class with methods for working with Objects within Flex.